# Trait Object function with parameters

Tags: rust

I'm trying to make a simple template engine (for sending messages with a different content), but faced a problem that I could not make a "virtual" method parametrized.

```
trait Evaluatable {
    fn evaluate(&self, dest: &mut impl std::io::Write);
}

struct A {}
struct B {}

impl Evaluatable for A {
    
    fn evaluate(&self, dest: &mut impl std::io::Write) {
        dest.write(b"value from A");
    }
}

impl Evaluatable for B {
    
    fn evaluate(&self, dest: &mut impl std::io::Write) {
        dest.write(b"value from B");
    }
}

struct Expression {
    values: Vec<Box<dyn Evaluatable>>
}

impl Expression {

    fn evaluate(&self, dest: &mut impl std::io::Write) {
        self.values.iter().for_each(|e| e.evaluate(dest))
    }
}

fn test() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    let expr = Expression { values: vec![Box::new(A{}), Box::new(B{})]};


    //Write to a file:
    let file = std::io::BufWriter::new(std::fs::File::create_new("afile")?);
    expr.evaluate(&mut file);

    //Write to the memory
    let data = Vec::new();
    expr.evaluate(&mut data);

    Ok(())
}
```

I understand that this is because of the object safety etc., but how to achive this? One can  advise to make Write also a dyn Object and pass Write as **&mut dyn Write**, but invoking a virtual method for every byte write is not what I would like it to be.
What is the common way do solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a BufWriter that holds a trait object. This defers the virtual call to flushes.

```rs
trait Evaluatable {
    fn evaluate(&self, dest: &mut BufWriter<&mut dyn std::io::Write>);
}
```

This is inconvenient if you have to do other things with the `BufWriter` since it now has a lifetime attached, so might not work for all cases. Some of those can be fixed by taking `BufWriter<Box<dyn Write>>`, but that's an extra allocation. It also means callers that use a different kind of buffered writer have to wrap it in another buffer.

Comment: Why not just take `&mut dyn std::io::Write`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, to decrease the number of calls to a virtual method for every byte write, only calling it when the buffer is full. But I thought about it as a solution: use only write(&[u8]) on &dyn Write.

Comment: @user3070377 note that you need to repeatedly call `write` until all the data has been written. Use `write_all` to write all data. This internally calls `write` by default, but those will be direct, inlineable function calls.